# Convert 12VDC to 15VDC?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have a 12V DC power supply and have a digital guitar pedal that needs 15V DC. There are a few other 9V/5V power circuits that I created using voltage regulators and a couple of capacitors, but I'm not familiar with how to go UP in voltage.

Answer (score 3):

In simple terms it's called a [boost converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter) and, fairly efficiently takes a lower supply voltage and transforms it to a higher supply voltage. You can buy plenty of off-the-shelf items that will do the job - try ebay.

One word of warning though - if it's to be used for audio applications (such as the guitar pedal) you may need to boost up to (say) 18V then use a linear voltage regulator to generate 15V. Typical candidate would be an LM7815 for this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the boost would need to be 18 then regulated down? I assume due to ripple or noise.

Comment: @JYelton I assume you know why and you are correct. A boost regulator will produce low/medium high frequency ripple that needs to be gotten rid of and raising the voltage to 18V then, using a linear regulator (which fights against ripple on the input supply side) should hopefully produce a clean 15v suitable for your pedal/audi device. What pedal is it BTW? If it's a rough old distortion pedal you might be able to live without the linear regulator.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with this, so was commenting to verify (but also to suggest that you include the reason why in the answer).

Comment: @JYelton - you seemed more flippant about earths on the moon and or planets LOL

Comment: Haha, yes, I change moods frequently and without warning! :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this is for an Eden WDTI bass preamp pedal. I think I'll go for the 18V boost and then regulate to 15V. Thanks!

Comment: Would this do it? http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Adjustable-Step-up-boost-Power-Converter-Module-XL6009-Replace-LM2577-/310717070508?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item48582e3cac

And if so, would it need to be filtered?